# Zf2 module versioning based on URL

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want that when I call myapp's url like `http://myapp/v1/admin` and `http://myapp/v2/admin` then I want to setup like that `module1/Admin` and `module2/Admin` so moudlewise versioning can be done.

As I have seen this https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-versioning.Is this applicable for above scenario or please help me out to get right way.
Thanks

Comment: @Bilal,How to use `Router` for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define routes in respective `module.config.php` files.

**module1**

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'v1_admin' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/v1/admin[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Module1\Controller\Admin',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

**module2**

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'v2_admin' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/v2/admin[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Module2\Controller\Admin',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply but I have asked another question with [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927874/zf2-versioning-module-in-zf2-skeleton-application] with diffrent info